# Flexibility with e-credit: could I use credit at one company to buy flight from another (partner) company?

Tags: air-travel, tickets, cancellations

With the covid pandemic, companies have now a much more flexible cancelling policy, allowing passengers to cancel a flight and giving them an e-credit to be used with them. I am concerned though that this would restrict a lot my flight options if I were to use that e-credit later on.

How flexible are these e-credit in general? That is, can you buy a flight from company B on company A's website? My first impression seems that it is not possible: having credit with Delta, I seem unable to buy an Air-France ticket, although Air France is their partner, and they even operate some flights together.

Now I also know that sometimes you might be able to buy tickets from a company that are not advertised on their website, but that show up on some aggregator website. I did this once for a complex multi-city ticket involving three distinct companies, though I bought it from the company offering the first flight.

To summarize, how much will I be bound to using credit within the same company? Is the trick (calling the company to ask for an unadvertised ticket) likely to work, or is the answer just it depends/no guarantee?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think there's going to be a general answer here. You can call the company you have the credit with, and ask if they can sell you the flight you're interested in. Probably they will say no, but sometimes they might say yes.

Answer (score 1):

A credit with Airline ABC is credit with Airline ABC.  Airline XYZ isn't going to accept that credit, and unless ABC regularly sells flights from XYZ via their website, ABC is unlikely to sell you a ticket for XYZ.

Airlines have been struggling through this time of reduced/restricted travel, they do not want to refund you so they issue credits instead.  Buying a ticket from XYZ means that ABC needs to pay for that ticket.  They'll lose any profit made on the sale, so really it ends up being no different that if they'd offered you a cash refund.

So no, unless they already sell those tickets for another airline directly, you're not going to be able to use your credit with another airline.

Comment: thanks! So what about the fact that I had been able to just call a company A and get a multi-city ticket for first flight with A, but second flight with B that was unrelated to A? It seems to indicates that sometimes this is possible?

Comment: @Matifou if A sold you a flight on B, then theres a relationship there - probably codeshare or they are members of the same partnership.